# How can I show specific posts on a WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have a page where I want to reference the titles from specific posts. This is my code with a loop right now -

```
<?php
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'post', 
'order' => 'ASC',
'cat' => '3',
);
$product_posts = get_posts( $args );?>

<p>
<?php foreach ( $product_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
</p>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I don't want to loop through every post though, I want to be able to single out certain posts. For example, where I have the `<p> get_the_title </p>` I want to be able to display it like -

```
<p>Title of Post 5 vs Title of Post 6</p>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try to store the titles in variables?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below:

On the **$catquery** query the **cat=3** is category ID so you can change with your specific category ID. And **post_per_page=5** is total count of post so also you can change as per your required.

```
<?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=5' ); ?>
<?php while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post(); ?>
 <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Thanks and let me know if any query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with post ID

```
$postid= array(144, 246);

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'post__in' => $postid,
   'posts_per_page'= 5
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
<?php while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
     <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```